# A couple of questions about a self-adjoint operator and its sequence of eigenvalues

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert sapce $(H, (\cdot,\cdot))$ such that $\sigma(A)\subset (0, +\infty)$ and consists of isolated eigenvalues $\lambda_r$, $r\ge 1$ of finite multiplicity wich satisfy
$$0<\lambda_1<\dots<\lambda_r<\dots$$
Let $(\cdot, \cdot)_A$ be the inner product
$$(u, v)_A= (Au, v).$$

I am trying to justify these 3 inequalities.

1. For all $u\in H$,
   $$\|u\|_A = (Au, u) \ge \lambda_1 (u, u).$$
   My question is: why it is $Au\ge\lambda_1 u$ instead of $Au=\lambda_1 u?$
2. Let $E_r$ be the eigensapce of $\lambda_r$ and
   $$ L_r = \oplus_{i=1}^r E_i, \qquad M_r = L_r^{\perp}.$$
   Why it is $(Av, v)\le \lambda_r (v, v)\ $ for all $v\in L_r$ and $(Aw, w)\ge\lambda_{r+1}(w, w) \ $ for all $w\in M_r$?

Could someone please help me to understand why these 3 inequalities hold true?

Thank you in advance!

${\bf EDIT:}$ I edit the question adding a comment related to the answer of Salcio. I agree with the fact that an orthogonal basis can be found such that $u=\sum_n a_n u_n$, but how to obtain the inequality, e.g., for the subspace $L_r$?
About me it should be something like
$$(Av, v) =\sum_l \lambda_l (v_l, v_l)\le l\lambda_l (v, v),$$
which is quite different from the claimed $(Av, v)\le \lambda_l (v, v)$.

I really hope someone could me help with some hint, I need to understand how this machinery works. Thank you, again.

Comment: $Au=\lambda_1u$ for some non-zero $u$, not for all $u$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy So in general it is $Au\ge \lambda_1 u$? I am sorry, I didn't understand your comment.

Comment: $Au$ and $u$ are elements of a Hilbert space, so expressions like $Au\geq \lambda_1 u$ are not even wrong, but simply not well-defined (which order relation are you using?).

Comment: @MaoWao thank you for your comment, I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

Eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are orthogonal.
In each "eigenvalue invariant subspace" (i.e. $E_r$) you find orthogonal basis and the sum of all these vectors forms orthogonal basis for $H$.
Let's denote these vectors by $u_n$.
Then, any $u$ one has $$u=\sum_n a_nu_n$$ for some numbers $a_n$.
Also $Au = \sum_r\sum_m A(a_mu_m) = \sum_r\sum_m \lambda_r a_mu_m = \sum_r\lambda_r\sum_ma_mu_m$. ,
Which gives $$<Au,u> = \sum_r \lambda_r\sum_m a_m^2<u_m,u_m>$$ 
Now you use relation on $\lambda$ to get
$$<Au,u> >= \lambda_1\sum_r\sum_m a_m^2<u_m,u_m> = \lambda_1<u,u>$$ 
The proof on the second point is similar.
That is, if we take an orthogonal basis in $E_r$, say $u_s,u_{s+1}, u_m$ then for any vector $u = \sum_{n=s} ^m a_nu_n$ we have $Au = \lambda_r \sum _{n=s}^m a_nu_n$. Also, vectors in different $E_r$ are orthogonal. Taking this all together we get for $u \in L_r$, $$u = \sum_r\sum_sa_su_s$$
$$Au = \sum_r \lambda_r\sum_s a_su_s$$ 
 then one uses orthogonality and estimates on $\lambda_r$ to get proper inequality.

Comment: It is not clear for me how to obtain the remaining two inequalities by using this approach. How to obtain that relations with $\lambda_r$ and $\lambda_{r+1}$?

Comment: Salcio, could you please help with the remaining two inequalities? I edited the question with my attempt based  on your answer, but it doesn't work. Thank you in advance!